# Terence tao numetical analysis 3.6.4 solution

Tags: real-analysis

All but the e part makes me sutruggle - I can't really find ways to approach it. I'll restate the problem:

> Let $X, Y$ be two finite sets. Prove that the $Y^X$ is finite and has
> the cardinality of $\#(Y^X)$ = $\#Y^{\#X}$.

Here $Y^X$ is the set of all funtions having domain X and range Y

My attempt: I'll use induction on $\#X$. With $\#X = 0$, or equivalently, $X = \emptyset$. We can prove that $\#(Y^X) = 1 = (\#Y)^0 (*)$.

We have this fact: $\forall f, f': f, f'$ be any functions from $\emptyset $ to $Y$, $f = f'$.

This is intuitive enough but here comes the definition of two functions being equal:

> $f, f'$ be two functions having some same domain X and same range then
> $f, f'$ are said to be equal if and only if $\forall x \in X: f(x) = f'(x)$

This is trivially true if $ X = \emptyset$. We've just proved (*) (in my opinion, it just seems a bit informal).

Now heres come the biggest part: How does we link the connection between $Y^X$ and $Y^{(X \setminus\{x\}) \cup \{x\}}$.(there exists such x since we consider $\#X \geq 1$ for the induction phase.

One idea would be taking use of this fact(I haven't proved it yet):

> $X$ is finite. If there exists a bijection from $X$ to $Y$ then $Y$ is
> finite and have the same cardinality as X does

My question:

1. Is my reasoning for the base case formal enough. If so, what to improve?
2. How should i proceed from there?

Thank you for reading :D

Comment: It's "Terence Tao" not, "Terrence tao".

Comment: Interesting: In Remark 3.3.6 he says that graphs "... describes the function completely", but then in Definition 3.3.7 requires that for functions to be equal they need to have the same codomain. Then graphs don't completely describe a function. Graph and codomain do, for him. So many Calculus books don't made their mind about that. I wouldn't expect him to fall into not deciding whether codomains were going to be part of his definition of functions or not.

Comment: [Zorich](https://zr9558.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/mathematical-analysis-zorich1.pdf) does a better job. I think to remember Apostol does too.

Comment: $Y^X=Y^{(X \setminus\{x\}) \cup \{x\}}=Y^{X \setminus\{x\}}\times Y^{\{x\}}$.